# Trying to connect to a database but getting network-related or instance-specific error along with error: 52

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, ssms

Trying to spin up a .NET project with SQL Server Management Studio but I am getting this error when I try to run a `update-database` in my Package Manager Console:

> Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>
> (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.)
>
> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified
>
> ClientConnectionId:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
> Error Number:2,State:0,Class:20
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.)"

I am not sure if this error is coming from my connection strings or from Management Studio. Here is my connection string inside `web.config`:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" 
         connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-ContactWeb-20201025050320.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-ContactWeb-20201025050320;Integrated Security=True" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: How did you generate your connection string?

Comment: I just built the solution when originally making the project and searched up that this could potentially be why the server isn't connecting/

Comment: _Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled._ So have you downloaded and installed SQL Server Express?

Comment: SQL Server Express is downloaded and installed. How can I verify that runtime feature is enabled?

Answer (score 0):

I also had this error. In my case, this error was because I downloaded the wrong SQL server Express installer file. I downloaded the 2014 version of the file, and the Windows site gave out several installation files, I chose a file that weighs 256 MB, and I had to download a file that weighs 1.2 GB.